# Maintaining a queue using structures in C

Tags: c, struct, queue

If I input 'E 5' I need to enqueue 5 onto the queue with no output. If I input 'D' I need to print the dequeued element.
Below is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct queue{
int start;//first element index
int end;//last element index
int size;//length of queue
int *ptr;//actual queue
}queue;
queue* createQueue(int x){
  queue* Q=(queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
  Q->start=0;
  Q->end=0;
  Q->size=1;
  Q->ptr[0]=x;
  return Q;
}
void enqueue(int x, queue*qptr, int i){
  qptr->size++;//increase size
  qptr->end++;//increase index of last element
  qptr->ptr[i]=x;
  return;
}
void dequeue(queue*qptr){
  if(qptr->size==0){
    printf("Empty\n");
    return;
  }
  printf("%d\n",qptr->ptr[qptr->start]);
  qptr->start++;
  qptr->size--;
}
int main(){
  char a; int i=0;int j;queue* qptr;
  while(scanf("%c",&a)!=-1){
  if(a=='E'){
    if(i==0){
      scanf("%d",&j);
      qptr =createQueue(j);
      i++;
    }
    else{
      scanf("%d",&j);
      enqueue(j, qptr, i);
      i++;
    }
  }
  else if(a=='D'){
    if(i==0){printf("Empty\n");}
    else {dequeue(qptr);i++;}
  }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

I don't understand what are my errors because it seems correct to me but the code doesn't compile. Please help me.

Comment: Your code compiles but with a warning - heed that warning. In `qptr->size = 0;` where does `qptr` point to?

Comment: @AdrianMole The struct that I had created when I called the first `if` in `int main()`.....right?

Comment: But you're attempting to access that struct ***before*** you create it. See the problem yet?

Comment: `queue* qptr;  qptr->size=0;` **that** code. Where does `qptr` point again? That's *undefined behavior* straight out of the chute in `main`.

Comment: @AdrianMole Ah yes, I have edited it now. Do you still see something wrong? Sorry, both C and structs are new to me so there are bound to be hiccups.

Comment: You said "the code doesn't compile" . Yes it does, but just as before, if you pay attention to your warnings and treat them as errors you will continue to find other problems. [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/8rTYxqsvW). And all of that is before you even *run* the code for logistical errors. Once the code *runs* you need to *debug* it using a *debugger*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, that helps. It so happens that I'm using Replit, and all it says is 'Illegal instruction'- no specific warning or anything of that sort.